# Convert the following piece of code into functional paradigm

Tags: scala

I have a piece that works fine. I just want to convert it into functional style. Problem is what collection function will I write to convert a collection into a value. This is the signature for an update method for UpdateStateByKey function which is used in spark streaming.

```
def updateFunction(newValues: Seq[(Int)], runningCount: Option[(Int)]): Option[(Int)] = 
{
   var result: Option[(Int)] = null

   if(newValues.isEmpty){ 
         result=Some(runningCount.get)
      }
   else
   {
        newValues.foreach 
      { x => 
        {
             if(runningCount.isEmpty){
             result=Some(x)
        }
         else
        {
              result=Some(x+runningCount.get) 
        }
        } 
      }
   }
  result
}
```

It will be called by this

```
val reducedRDD=keyValuelines.reduceByKey((x,y)=>(x+y))
val updatedRdd= reducedRDD.updateStateByKey(updateFunction)
```

So effectively

If the newValues is empty, get the runningCount. Else:

1. If runningCount is empty - sum the newValues
2. If running count is present - sum the newValues and the output with running counts

I do not want to use foreach, because it returns nothing. All other collection functions do not seem to fit this criteria.

I have come up with this code as my attempt to convert it to functional code. Can someone please confirm that this is correct?

```
def updateFunctionVal(newValues: Seq[(Int)], runningCount: Option[(Int)]): Option[(Int)] = {

    val result = if (newValues.isEmpty) { //check if the key is present in new batch if not then return the old values
      Some(runningCount.get)
    }
    else {
      runningCount match {
        case x if runningCount.isEmpty => Some(newValues.fold(0)(_ + _))
        case _ => Some(newValues.fold(0)(_ + _) + runningCount.get)
      }
    }
    result
  }
```

Comment: What does this function do? Looks like it returns the _last_ item in the given `newValues` plus the value of `runningCount`, if it exists. Is that it? Or is this meant to return the _sum_ of `newValues` (it doesn't)?

Comment: Anyway, take a look at collection functions like `fold`, `foldLeft`, `reduce` etc.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason for `runningCount` to be an `Option[Int]` rather than an `Int`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the description hidden in the post, here's one implementation using `reduceOption`:

```
/*
If the newValues is empty, get the runningCount. Else:
  If running count is present - sum the newValues and add runningCount
  else - sum the newValues
 */
def updateFunction(newValues: Seq[(Int)], runningCount: Option[(Int)]): Option[Int] = {
  newValues
    .reduceOption(_ + _)                // sum of values, or None
    .map(_ + runningCount.getOrElse(0)) // add runningCount or 0 to sum
    .orElse(runningCount)               // if newValues was empty, just return runningCount
}

println(updateFunction(Seq(), Some(3)))     // Some(3)
println(updateFunction(Seq(4, 5), Some(3))) // Some(12)
println(updateFunction(Seq(4, 5), None))    // Some(9)
println(updateFunction(Seq(), None))        // None
```

Answer (score 1):

<del>So just to be clear on the intended output of the function: if `newValues` is empty, just return `runningCount`. If it's not empty, return whatever the last value is, with whatever is in `runningCount` added to it, if present. Is that correct? What if `newValues` is empty and `runningCount` is `None`? Right now you throw an exception. Here's a version that returns `None` in that case:</del>

```
def updateFunction(newValues: Seq[Int], runningCount: Option[Int]): Option[Int] = {
  newValues.lastOption match {
    case None => runningCount
    case Some(x) => Some(x + runningCount.getOrElse(0))
  }
}
```

<del>Or essentially the same, but a bit more compact:</del>

```
def updateFunction(newValues: Seq[Int], runningCount: Option[Int]): Option[Int] = {
  newValues.lastOption.map(_ + runningCount.getOrElse(0)).orElse(runningCount)
}
```

Edit: your second attempt has entirely different logic and outputs. It would help if you clarify in plain english what you want the function to do.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree. The second one is completely different logic. My sincere apologies for the confusion. If the newValues is empty, get the runningCount else 1. runningCount is empty - sum the newValues  2. running count is present - sum the newValues and the output with running counts

Comment: @Srinivas please edit the question to include this explanation, and try to state is as clearly as possible. For example - seems like you never return `None` (empty `Option`) - is that the case? If so - why would the method return an `Option` at all?

Comment: I have provided clarification, I apologise for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understood the logic you're trying to implement:

You have a running count, and a list of values which should all be added to the count. I believe you're looking for is the `foldLeft/Right` operation:

```
def update(newValues: Seq[(Int)], runningCount: Option[(Int)]) =
    newValues.foldLeft[Option[(Int)]](runningCount)((count, value) =>
        count match {
            case Some(initial) => Some(initial + value)
            case None => Some(value)
        })
```

<del>Note that a regular `fold` wouldn't work here, as it's only defined for types extending `Int` (I believe this has to do with the associative rules, as `fold` doesn't define whether it's doing the folding from left or right)</del>

Comment: I apologise, Please look at my edits again. I have provided clarification

Comment: "... only defined for types extending `Int`" **not true**. `fold()` works for all kinds of types. The relationship between element type and result type is more restricted than with the `foldLeft`/`Right` variants.

Comment: Srinivas, I don't see how your edit change what I wrote. You still need the sum of all *present* option values in the running count and new values, you just phrased it differently. @jwvh - yes, this was a brain fart, apologies

Comment: @AlexSavitsky, at the point you wrote, I realized that did not provided full input. Let me test it, it will take a minute for me to understand your code :)

Comment: Deleted the post when I realized it doesn't give expected result for some cases; undeleted it after fixing